# Analytical solution to the transient advection-diffusion equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the 1D steady-state advection-diffusion equation and corresponding boundary conditions:

$v\frac{dc}{dx} - D\frac{d^2c}{dx^2} = f\quad\forall x\in(0,1)$

$c(x=0) = c(x=1)=0$

The analytical solution is:

$c(x)= \frac{f}{v}\left(x-\frac{1-\mathrm{exp}\left[\frac{v}{D}x\right]}{1-\mathrm{exp}\left[\frac{v}{D}\right]}\right)$

Where $v$, $D$, and $f$ are constants. Now my question is, once I turn this into an unsteady problem:

$\frac{dc}{dt} + v\frac{dc}{dx} - D\frac{d^2c}{dx^2} = f\quad\forall x\in(0,1)\times(0,\mathcal{I}]$

$c(x=0,t) = c(x=1,t)=0 \quad\forall t\in(0,\mathcal{I}]$

$c(x,t=0) = 0$

What's the analytical solution for this?

Comment: do you want a travelling wave solution? since the solution will match what you have pretty much.

Comment: Yes, I want that solution. Because I want to compare this analytical solution for a given time with my numerical approximations

Answer (score 0):

$$
z = x - ct
$$
thus we have
$$
\partial_t = -c\frac{d}{dz}\\
\partial_x = \frac{d}{dz}
$$
thus you end up with an equation
$$
-c\frac{dc}{dz}+v\frac{dc}{dz}-D\frac{d^2c}{dz^2}=f
$$
so if we map
$$
-c+v \to \bar{v}\\
$$
then your equation becomes
$$
\bar{v}\frac{dc}{dz}-D\frac{d^2c}{dz^2}=f 
$$
c.f with your solution that you already found. You have to work with the initial conditions carefully but looking at the way you have wrote the post out, I am sure its just a point in the right direction (at least the direction I am thinking) that you need.